# Using Weinre to Debug in Android WebView

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug a WebView in my Android application.I did some research and found weinre is quite useful.What I am using is the weinre of PhoneGap [PhoneGap Debugging Tool.](http://debug.phonegap.com)
However what make me confused is that it only runs fine when I use it to debug in a native browser,not when I open my application.When I open my application it does not show the webview for me to inspect.

Anyone knows how to make it work with the webview? Or I have to install Weinre locally to make it works?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        this.webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


        final String htmlPre = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"> <script src='http://172.16.0.135:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous'></script> <script>alert('hello')</script></head><body style='margin:0; pading:0; background-color: black;'>";  
        final String htmlCode = 
                " <embed style='width:100%; height:100%' src='http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0/FLVPlayer.swf?fullscreen=true&video=http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/pl-600.flv&autoplay=true' " +
                "  autoplay='true' " +
                "  quality='high' bgcolor='#000000' " +
                "  name='VideoPlayer' align='middle'" + // width='640' height='480' 
                "  allowScriptAccess='*' allowFullScreen='true'" +
                "  type='application/x-shockwave-flash' " +
                "  pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' />" +
                "";
        final String htmlPost = "</body></html>";

        this.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", htmlPre+htmlCode+htmlPost, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            }
        });
Now I'm trying something new like this and it does not work anymore, any suggestion? Thanks :)
```

Comment: Have you added that .js link into your html page which you want to debug?

Comment: yes I did, so it runs fine when I open the browser, not with my app. I upload it to hit.somee.com.

Comment: have you enable javascript for your webview are you using webview..setJavaScriptEnabled(true); ??

Comment: Oh yes thanks a lot, silly me, I forgot to enable the JavaScript. By the way the webpage I want to debug is not the other link I gave in previous comment, that was just to test Weinre in WebView. I am trying to debug a webview that use webview.loaddata, not webview.loadurl, is it possible to do so? Because I had tried JsHybugger before and it could only be used with webview.loadurl

Answer (score 0):

I installed weinre on my dev laptop (debian) and worked like a charm from any browser and also from Android webview.

It's as simple as installing weinre with node.js:

> sudo npm -g install weinre

Documentation in [documentation](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)

Finally a tip: When starting your server remember to change

> --boundHost [hostname | ip address | -all-]

if your server is not at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you did find out how to debug with weinre while using webviews loadDataWithBaseURL(..) but here is my solution. You need to use the first argument as your local address where weinre is running:

```
 m_webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://192.168.1.3:8080/", ...)
```

Before the fix I was using this:

```
 m_webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
```

the first argument in my case was assets folder because I do have there some javascript and css files.. If needed you can move those files to weinre folder on your PC (staticWebDir - usually located c:\Users[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\weinre\web) than your mobile webpage will have all styling and javascript you use.

Answer (score -1):

jsHybugger: http://www.jshybugger.org/ works in webView or native browser.

It lets you set breakpoints, singlestep, catch exceptions, and interact with the JS/DOM environment. You can use it from Eclipse or from a Chrome or Chrome-compatible debugger on the remote desktop. It can be used with apps that create their own webView.

However, you have to install a few files -- but probably no more complicated to use than weinre. it does extensively modify the JS files (on the fly, transparently to the user) to enable all this debugging -- webKit really should support javascript debugging natively.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that JSHybugger can only debug html files that I have in local folder, not Webview that loads data from my WebService. I tried it before but failed.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I was using javascript loaded from an asset.  I think it has a proxy that intercepts all requests and 'instruments' things loaded from remote servers -- but I don't know.   However it does work (for me) in a WebView class browser (in addition to the default web browser)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, maybe I should give it a try again. Actually, I didn't dig into jshybugger much last time, I might miss something there.